# How can i distinguish in .net from columns that are unnamed in the query?

Tags: .net, sql-server

When i run the following query (from c# code to an sql server connection):

```
select GetDate() Named, GetDate() Column2, Getdate(), getdate(), getdate() Named
```

the resulting DataTable has the folowing columns: Named, Column2, Column1, Column3, Named1
is there any way to know from the .NET that Column1 & Column3 where unnamed in the query?

running the same query in the management studio show the exact names from the select: un named column for Column1 & Column3 and Named instead of Named1

Note: just to make this clear - the SQL query is NOT the issue - the issue is how get the correct schema that is returned by the server.

Comment: As a shot in  the dark, I would say : If you have a SqlDataAdapter, you may try to look in its TableMappings collection at the mapping for your table. Then, for each of the ColumnMappings  of thisTableMapping, compare the DataSetColumn property with the SourceColumnProperty (GetDataColumnBySchemaAction might also be interesting) Hope this will help

Comment: @jbl if i define the table mapping i need to know in advance what the columns are - the whole point is how to detect correctly what the server sends me

Comment: seems like these infos are nested deep inside the SlqCommand.MetaData._metaDataArray (have a look with the debugger) These properties being internal/private, I'm afraid only reflection will help you to get to these infos

Comment: @jbl Thanks - i found it using your tip. Sadly this information is not past on from the SqlCommand to the data storage classes like DataTable & DataColumn. And even then this information is only available through reflection - so i'll pass and just do what i do now - Assume that any column that its name is ColumnN is an unnamed column

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest to add aliases to each column using AS keyword, so it will be no problem accessing data from DataTable.

Comment: I have no problem accessing the data whatsoever - i am having problem finding out the schema as it is returned from the server - something that i know that could be done since management console that is a .net app does correctly